# Computing powers of a special matrix fast

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrences

I've got an $n\times n$ matrix that is upper-triangular (all zeros below diagonal), diagonal entries are positive, and entries that are not on the diagonal are either $0$ or $1$. An example matrix looks like this. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
69 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 100 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 15 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 15 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 300 
\end{pmatrix}$$ I'm interested in the *upper-right* entry of a large power (say $A^k$) of this matrix with computations done in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some fixed prime $p$. Is it possible to compute this faster than usual for this kind of matrices? I'm looking for runtimes something similar to $O(n^2)$ preprocessing and $O(n\lg k)$ per query.

Comment: Do you mean for a given $A$ and $p$ you want to compute the upper right entries for many different $k$?  Then it may make sense to precompute the Jordan normal form (of course the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries)..

Comment: @RobertIsrael: yes for the first question. But wouldn't computing the Jordan normal form end up taking at least $O(n^3)$ precomputation time (given the eigenvalues, I still would need to compute several kernels)? That's unfortunately too much for my purpose.

Comment: Your matrix structure doesn't seem particularly special.  How can you expect time linear in $n$ when the size of the output is $\Theta(n^2)$?

Comment: Actually the output size is $O(1)$. I'm interested in the upper-right entry of the power.

Comment: Right, sorry I can't read today.

Comment: You’re computing in a finite field, so when you say the diagonal entries are positive, do you just mean nonzero?

Comment: I mean they are nonzero modulo $p$. Sorry for the confusion.